# IntlRateV2Request error usps

Tags: php, asp.net, usps

I'm just really confused by the whole thing.  My domestic shipping is working fine.  My international shipping is NOT working.

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=InitRateV2&XML=
<IntlRateV2Request USERID="xxxxxxxxxxx">
  <Package ID="1ST">
    <Pounds>15</Pounds>
    <Ounces>0</Ounces>
    <Machinable>True</Machinable>
    <MailType>Package</MailType>
    <GXG>
         <POBoxFlag>Y</POBoxFlag>
          <GiftFlag>Y</GiftFlag>
    </GXG>
   <ValueOfContents>200</ValueOfContents>
    <Country>Canada</Country>
    <Container>RECTANGULAR</Container>
    <Size>LARGE</Size>
    <Width>10</Width>
    <Length>15</Length>
    <Height>10</Height>
    <Girth>0</Girth>
    <CommercialFlag>N</CommercialFlag>
  </Package>
</IntlRateV2Request>
```

this give a error.

user Id already updated as production mode..

```
<Error>
    <Number>80040b1a</Number>
    <Description>API Authorization failure. InitRateV2 is not a valid API name for this protocol.</Description>
    <Source>UspsCom::DoAuth</Source>
</Error>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `InitRateV2` be `IntlRateV2`?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but your error message says "InitRateV2 is not a valid API name for this protocol."

Looking at the XML you're sending the root tag is `<IntlRateV2Request USERID="xxxxxxxxxxx">`.

It might be a typo in your code.  Have you tried:

```
`http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=IntlRateV2&XML=`?
```

In other words, **Intl**, not **Init**.